# Paypal web payments standard - Refunds. Can they be done via the Api?

Tags: php, paypal

I've been pulling my hair out going through the Paypal documentation maze. My question is simple. **Is it possible to instigate a refund via an API call with web payments standard?**

I know you can with the pro version as I've found various bits of documentation dotted around the place. I also found [This bit of info](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_RefundTransaction#id09BKC0JC0PM) from Paypal but it doesn't seem to mention any version requirements or a url to send the call to.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. RefundTransaction can also process refunds from Standard or Express Checkout transactions.
It won't work for Payflow Link or Pro however.